# __NSCFString string error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I've got the following error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

while implementing AFNetworking's method POST (resultDict contains images):

```
str=[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
[manager1 POST:str
    parameters:resultDict
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"Post JSON: %@",responseObject);
       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
           NSLog(@"Post Error: %@",error);
       }];
```

As I understood the problem is in parsing but there is no problem in almost same code in my project.

I've paused running right before the POST method and no variables was equal to nil

Have anybody faced this problem?

Comment: The problem is `NSString` has `+string`, but no `-string`: It's a class method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Check your stack trace. What is calling `string`? The cause of this problem is that some variable is not the type you think it is (or that `AFNetworking` thinks it is). There is some type that has a `string` method, but it getting a `NSString` instead of that type.

My hunch is that `[POST:parameters:success:failure:]` is getting confused by your URL, and may have a bug in how it manages its `NSURLComponents` (which has a `-string` method), and feels suspicious here.

Check `str` before you send it. This encoding may be incorrect. You can't necessarily use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` to encode the entire URL (not all of the URL is the query). You'll often get away with it, but it's not really correct.

Comment: it fails sometimes with no using URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet. And deleting it didn't solve the problem. str = (__NSCFString *) at the breaking moment